# How to use Patch and JsonPatchDocument<T> to update multiple records at same time?

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core

I have an object that I would like to allow partial updates on. We will just call this object `Customer` and theoretically these `Customer`'s show up in a grid on the front end.

My grid allows for updating multiple `Customer`'s and then saving calling my Restful backend. However, using `JsonPatchDocument` - I don't see anyway to send a "batch patch" to where I specify the ID of the object to pass. For instance pretend this is my class:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and I want to update `Customer.ID` = 1 with `Customer.Name` = JimBob AND I want to submit an update for `Customer.ID` = 2 with `Customer.Name` = Billy --- how would the Json look?

The example from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-2.2) website doesn't make it obvious, how I know what ID that is? Do I add it to the path like `/id/1/customerName`?

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/customerName",
    "value": "Barry"
  }
]
```

Comment: You don't specify the item by ID, you specify the array order number in the path, e.g: `/customers/0`, or `/customers/2`. The patching must ocurr on the same object (the same array) you are showing for that to work.

Comment: I don't understand how that is restful. So my backend knows nothing about what my front end is showing (it doesn't know state) --- so the front end has a subset of customers it is showing, and it wants to change 3 customers in that subset. But it's an all or nothing proposition ---if one of the 3 fails, they all fail. The backend obviously knows all the customers, therefore it's array is much larger. How do I know which to update?

Comment: The patch operation applies to a "resource". If that resource is a "group of customers", you got it from a GET request to a URL (an URL is a  "resource locator"): then you need to specify the SAME resource to patch (the same URL you made the GET to, with a PATCH verb)... so to be stateless, your backend needs to retrieve the same resource, then patch it with the commands sent on the JSONPatch payload. If it was otherwise (you specified the IDs on the jsonpatch), you'd be "locating the resource to patch" with the payload, which would not be restful either.

Comment: I get it - thanks for answering - question about that however...

What if the same url retrieves a different list? In this case we are sorting customers by a certain field that changes rather often to put them in a list, so the backend list could be different than the front end list.

Comment: for instance: if customers had a field like `CurrentLocation` and we pulled in the following customers: `Customers?CurrentLocation=mall` and by the time we submitted the `patch` request multiple customers had left the mall, and new customers had entered the mall?

Now when I do `Customers?CurrentLocation=mall` I get a different result on the backend than what the front end is showing?